# How to read external properties with dynamic file using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to perform something similar to the following code using Spring

```
class MyPropotypeBean {

    /* We can not for static file name like 
    * @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abcd", locations = "file:conf/a2z.properties")
    */
    public MyPropotypeBean(String propFileLocation) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
                input = new FileInputStream(propFileLocation);
                prop.load(input);
                gMapReportUrl = prop.getProperty("gMapReportUrl");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
                ...
        }

    }
}
```

I want propFileLocation dynamically injected something similar to  the following.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abcd", locations = "file:conf/" + propFileLocation + ".properties")
```

I know we cannot achieve using annotation. How Can I do it pragmatically?

Comment: maybe have the list of dynamic files in a different static property file?

Comment: Use the environment, Luke (environment variable or some property)

Comment: list of files are dynamic and each prototype beans must have different values based on properties file. environment variable can contain multiple prop file names we need to create same number of prototype beans.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring `ResourceBundleMessageSource`. It helps to load external properties. Have a look at [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/resourcebundlemessagesource-spring-example).

```
@Value("${file.directory}")
private String propFileLocation;
//getters and setters
 @Bean
 public MessageSource messageSource() {
   ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
   messageSource.setBasenames("file:conf/"+propFileLocation);
   messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
   return messageSource;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not what I want. I want to create prototype bean by injecting properties file dynamically.  The better approach of your solution in my case would be following   
 `@Bean
@Resource
public Properties config(String propFileLocation) throws IOException {
return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(new ClassPathResource(propFileLocation));
}`